# How to unit test an EF transaction that involves multiple repositories

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core, mocking

i have this code that starts a transaction and call two different repositories

```
            using var transaction = await context.Database.BeginTransactionAsync();
            try
            {
                var data1 = await callRepository1();
                var data2 = await callRepository2(); 
                await transaction.CommitAsync();
                
            }
        
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                await transaction.RollbackAsync();
                throw;
            }
```

i can easily mock "callRepository1" and "callRepository2"
but how i can mock the context so i can use "BeginTransactionAsync" "CommitAsync" and "RollbackAsync"

Answer (score 0):

To mock the `context` and its `transaction-related` methods (`BeginTransactionAsync`, `CommitAsync`, and `RollbackAsync`), you can create an `interface` that defines these methods and implement it in a `mock` class for testing purposes.
First, define an interface that represents the context and its transaction-related methods:

```
    public interface IDbContext
    {
        Task<IDbTransaction> BeginTransactionAsync();
        Task CommitAsync();
        Task RollbackAsync();
    }
```

Next, create a `mock` class that implements the `IDbContext` interface:

```
public class MockDbContext : IDbContext
{
    public Task<IDbTransaction> BeginTransactionAsync()
    {
        // Implement the logic for beginning a transaction in your mock context
        // You can return a mock transaction object or any other suitable implementation for testing
        // For example:
        var mockTransaction = new Mock<IDbTransaction>();
        return Task.FromResult(mockTransaction.Object);
    }

    public Task CommitAsync()
    {
        // Implement the logic for committing a transaction in your mock context
        // For example:
        Console.WriteLine("Mock transaction committed.");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task RollbackAsync()
    {
        // Implement the logic for rolling back a transaction in your mock context
        // For example:
        Console.WriteLine("Mock transaction rolled back.");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Then in your test scenario, you can then instantiate the `MockDbContext` and use it to mock the context and its transaction-related methods:

```
// Create an instance of the mock context
var mockContext = new MockDbContext();

// Use the mock context in your code under test
using (var transaction = await mockContext.BeginTransactionAsync())
{
    try
    {
        var data1 = await callRepository1();
        var data2 = await callRepository2();
        await mockContext.CommitAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        await mockContext.RollbackAsync();
        throw;
    }
}
```

Using the `MockDbContext` class, you can simulate the behaviour of the context and its transaction-related methods in your test scenarios without relying on the actual database context.